# How to convert rows to columns without changing the data?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, pivot, crosstab, unpivot

This is DATA I have

```
   -----------------------------------------------
   | Name   | Subject    | Exam_type   | Marks   |
   -----------------------------------------------
   | Abc    | English    | Summative   |  10     |
   | Abc    | English    | Formatve    |  62     |
   | Abc    | Hindi      | Summative   |  13     |
   | Abc    | Hindi      | Formatve    |  49     |
   -----------------------------------------------
```

This is what I want

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Name   |Subject  | Summative  |  Formative  |  
-----------------------------------------------
| Abc    | English |    10      |    62       |
| Abc    | Hindi   |    13      |    49       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

How can I build the result?

I dont know what to use... but I tried it using PIVOT fn of sql but its needs aggregation and I dont want to perform any arithmetic on the data. only want to convert into columns

Crystal Reports cross tab is the other option I tried but failed to achieve this... Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I Assume that you work with Sql-Server.

There no kind of `Primary key` or `Unique Identifier` in your Sample data.

So, Assume that this is only one student data. If there more than you have to use `WHERE` clause as your requirement.

Note:*Syntax may very with your DBMS*

Here `cte` is you can consider as your table you don't need that:

Step 1:
Select marks as Exam_Type:

From sub query below part is return `marks` or `0` for Individual Exam_Type

```
CASE WHEN Exam_Type='Summative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END AS [Summative] -- for Summative 

CASE WHEN Exam_Type='Formative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END AS [Formative] -- for Formative
```

So after execution of sub query:

```
SELECT Name,[Subject],
CASE WHEN Exam_Type='Summative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END AS [Summative],
CASE WHEN Exam_Type='Formative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END AS [Formative]
FROM cte
```

Result Like:

```
Name    Subject  Summative  Formative
--------------------------------------
Abc     English   10         0
Abc     English   0         62
Abc     Hindi     13         0
Abc     Hindi     0         49
```

Now you can observe that each record has in only Specific Exam_Type has value other is `0`

So finally you need an aggregation to remove `0`

So your final query is below:

```
SELECT c.Name,c.[Subject],MAX(c.Summative) AS [Summative],MAX(c.Formative) AS [Formative]
FROM 
(SELECT Name,[Subject],
CASE WHEN Exam_Type='Summative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END AS [Summative],
CASE WHEN Exam_Type='Formative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END AS [Formative]
FROM cte) AS c
GROUP BY c.[Subject],c.[Name]
```

Output:

```
Name    Subject Summative   Formative
-------------------------------------
Abc     English     10         62
Abc     Hindi       13         49
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5560f2e373028a53b3ad164f2fa6ac9d)

Comment: I just posted this table as sample... the database is really very huge. I dont know why I am having problems in understanding the syntax in your query. Elaborate if you can. please

Comment: However English is no may first language . should it may more understandable!!

Comment: You did your best sir, but still the problem is the more exam types can be added later on and then this query will have no effect. But you did a really gud job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name, Subject,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Exam_Type = 'Summative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Summative,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Exam_Type = 'Formative' THEN Marks ELSE 0 END) AS Formative
FROM cte
GROUP BY Name, Subject;
```